# Nginx show custom PHP file

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have nginx directives like below

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php @rewrites;
}
location @rewrites {
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/;
rewrite ^ https://google.com permanent;
}
```

Above code works fine

But below code is not working , It shows 404 Not found nginx page, which means some permission has been changed  to /rewrite/blog.php , I checked and permission is 755 .. also I tried to use full path like /var/httdocs/domain.com/rewrite/blog.php , still its not working.

Accessing domain.com/rewrite/blog.php seperately on browser too working fine.

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php @rewrites;
}
location @rewrites {
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
rewrite ^ /rewrite/blog.php last;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Sorry  It shows 404 Not found